# Getting same output everytime

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

This a simple number guessing game. If you guessed the number right, it outputs "You win!!!", but if the number of tries (`numberofguesses`) is exceeded, it should output "You lose", but it is showing "You win!!!" even though I checked the values of `numberofguesses`, `secretnum` and `guess` after the `while` loop. Answer in simple words, I'm a beginner.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int secretnum = 7;
    int guess = 0;
    int numberofguesses = 3;
    while (secretnum != guess && numberofguesses != 0) {
        cout << "enter your guess: ";
        cin >> guess;
        --numberofguesses;
    }
    if (secretnum = guess && numberofguesses != 0) {
        cout << "You win!!!";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You lose";
    }
}
```

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` for comparison

Comment: `secretnum = guess`, something is wrong here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mistaken the *assignment* operator `=` with the *comparison* operator `==`.

In this line here:

```
 if (secretnum = guess && numberofguesses != 0) 
            cout << "You win!!!";
```

Change it to:

```
if (secretnum == guess && numberofguesses != 0) {
        cout << "You win!!!";
```